# Internal Server Error (500) with OVH Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, database-connection, ovh

When I use my php website with a localhost mysql database, it is working fine.
Here is the PDO file with localhost database

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'aen');

define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
```

But I have to put my website on OVH server with database server.
With PhpMyAdmin on OVH server, I can access to my database tables.

Here is the PhpMyAdmin connexion [image: Screenshot phpmyadmin]:

When I try to connect my Website on my OVH Mysql Database server, I got internal server error.
I just modify my PDO file like this :

```
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOST', 'aenproybdd.mysql.db');
// or define('DB_HOST', '51.91.236.193');
define('DB_NAME', 'aenproybdd');

define('DB_USER', 'aenproybdd');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PASSWORD', password);
```

What is wrong ? If you have any idea, it will be hepful for me.

Thanks a lot, Thomas.

Comment: You can enable error logging on your webserver to see what part of your code is erroring so that you don't have to guess what is wrong.

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: I don't manage to see server logs :-(

Comment: I find logs but there is no entry for my internal error

Comment: The problem in my code is on connection. But it is not a source code problem because when I use parameters for localhost database, it is working fine.